# Extracting variables from array keys with suffix or prefix PHP

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am extracting variables from an array and works fine , but just happens that in same file I have news items from different category with array that has same key names so they get mixed up  and first set loaded takes over, what I need is a prefix or suffix for the variable so I can differentiate one from another

```
function get_extra_fields($item){
    $item->extra_fields = K2ModelItem::getItemExtraFields($item->extra_fields);
    foreach ( $item->extra_fields as $key => $extraField ){

        $getkey  = strtolower($extraField->name);
        $getkey  = str_replace(' ', '', $getkey);
        global $$getkey;
        $$getkey = $extraField->value;
    }

}
```

and it is called within foreach for 3 different categories

```
foreach($get_gcat1 as $row => $item){
   get_extra_fields($item);
  echo $newstitle;
}

foreach($get_cat2 as $row => $item){
   get_extra_fields($item);
   echo $newstitle;
}

foreach($get_cat3 as $row => $item){
   get_extra_fields($item);
   echo $newstitle;
}
```

any help is appreciated. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange way for creating global variables, but here is something that may do what you want:

```
function get_extra_fields($item, $prefix){
    $item->extra_fields = K2ModelItem::getItemExtraFields($item->extra_fields);
    foreach ( $item->extra_fields as $key => $extraField ){
        $getkey  = strtolower($extraField->name);
        $getkey  = str_replace(' ', '', $getkey);
        $GLOBALS[$prefix.$getkey] = $extraField->value;
    }
}


foreach($get_gcat1 as $row => $item){
  get_extra_fields($item, 'cat1_');
  echo $cat1_newstitle;
}

foreach($get_cat2 as $row => $item){
   get_extra_fields($item, 'cat2_');
   echo $cat2_newstitle;
}

foreach($get_cat3 as $row => $item){
   get_extra_fields($item, 'cat3_');
   echo $cat3_newstitle;
}
```